# Set Fragment EditText from the parent Activty

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ProfileFragment class which contains two setters:

```
public void setPseudo(String pseudo){
    textPseudo.setText(pseudo);
}
public void setEmail(String email){
    textEmail.setText(email);
}
```

And in my Activity I would like to call these functions:

```
user = new ProfileFragment();

if (intent != null) {

    user.setPseudo(intent.getStringExtra(USER_PSEUDO));
    user.setEmail(intent.getStringExtra(USER_EMAIL));
}
```

It says "can't resolve method...".
Does it mean I can't do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have a `Profile` class with setters? Not a `Fragment`?

---

Fragments generally don't use setters, they use arguments.

Reason being: If you call `setEmail`, and then you called to some view `setText` within the new Fragment, you get a `NullPointerException` because that `TextView` was never initialized

```
Fragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
if (intent != null) {
    args.putAll(intent.getExtras());
}
profileFragment.setArguments(args);

// Show new Fragment
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .replace(R.id.content, profileFragment)
    .commit();
```

And inside your Fragment's `onCreateView`, you can now use this, for example

```
final Bundle args = getArguments();

String pseudo = "";
if (args != null) {
    pseudo = args.getString(YourActivity.USER_PSEUDO);
}
textPseudo.setText(pseudo);
```

Comment: Right, you need to statically import it

Comment: You declared it in another Activity is the exact reason that you need to either import it, or qualify it, as I have in my updated answer

Comment: I tried this in the new Activity : public static final String USER_PSEUDO = ""; it says it's already defined in scope ... I don't understand.

Comment: Without seeing your full code, all I can say is check your import statements

Comment: Seriously passing variables from Activities to Fragments is this complicated....? I'm totally lost here

Comment: Lost with what? It's not that complicated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment  Fragments are designed to be isolated elements from the Activity. If you really need an updatable view, then you want a custom `View` class, not a Fragment.